How to show a restricted Outlook work calendar's events in iOS Calendar app, alongside events from other Google calendars
I would like to see personal Google Calendar events alongside work Outlook Calendar events in the Calendar app in iOS, to get a full view of my availability. My work Outlook account is fairly restricted and managed through Okta. I'm familiar with Google Calendar but less familiar with Outlook.
I tried a couple of things which didn't work
Failed attempt 1: adding my work Exchange account in iOS
I followed these instructions to connect to an Exchange server. I got mixed messages about the success of this at different screens. First, I was directed to log in at Okta, logged in, and saw "Sign In Verified"

Then when I returned to Settings, I saw "Exchange Account Unable to verify account information."

I tapped "okay" and "save" and deselected "mail", "contacts", and "reminders", leaving "calendars" checked.

Went back to the iOS Calendar app, but no work calendar events appeared. Tapped on "calendars" and the work exchange account appeared at the top of the list of calendars, but there were no calendars shown under the work exchange account (the way several calendars appear under my Gmail account).

I'm stuck here unable to get the work calendar's events to show up in iOS calendar.
Failed attempt 2: using a third party service (Clockwise) to sync events
Tried to log in / create an account with Clockwise. Went to "log in" > "sign in with Microsoft" and authenticated. Saw a message of "need admin approval", which isn't going to happen.
Failed attempt 3: sharing my Outlook calendar with myself
From the Outlook web app, I selected my work calendar and went to "sharing and permissions" and entered my personal gmail address. Saw "You don't have permission to share your calendar with [personal gmail address]"


The message "Unable to verify account information" means you aren't properly logged into your Exchange account, that's why you don't see any events for that calendar. Could it be that logging into Exchange is restricted to approved devices, and yours is not? I don't know Okta, but Microsoft Entra can be configured that way. You may want to contact your company's IT department and ask them if that's the case.
